# Relative path not pointing to desired directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, relative-path, pdfkit

I have the following code:

```
import datetime as date
import os
import pdfkit

import getpass #Gets me current username

username = getpass.getuser()

path = f"/home/{username}/Data"
relative_path = os.path.relpath(path, os.getcwd())
destination = os.path.join(relative_path, 'data.pdf')
pdfkit.from_url('www.google.com', f'{destination}/data.pdf')
```

I want the pdf to be saved in windows equivalent of `/home/[username]/datafolder`. I don't really need to use use linux or mac but for academic reasons i have decided to use the relative path method.

This code makes sense to me but for some reason it is not the directory i want it to be because when i specify the path this way the pdf generator, generates an error.

```
Error: Unable to write to destination                              
Exit with code 1, due to unknown error.
```

I know the error is in the last line of code where i have specified '`/relative_path/data.pdf`'. Could you please advise how i can resolve this issue?

---

**Update 1:**

### As suggested by @Matthias I have updated the code but I am still getting the same error

**Update 2:**

I tried:

```
from pathlib import Path
destination = Path.home()
try:  
    os.mkdir(destination\Data)  
except OSError as error:  
    print(error)
```

But it is still not pointing to the directory `Data`

---

***Update 3***
I know i am getting closer:

```
import pdfkit
import datetime as date
import calendar
import os.path
import getpass

username = getpass.getuser()

path = f"/home/{username}/Data"
os.makedirs(relative_path, exist_ok=True)
#start = os.getcwd()
relative_path = os.path.relpath(path, os.getcwd())
destination = os.path.join(relative_path, 'data.pdf')

pdfkit.from_url('www.google.com', f'{relative_path}/data.pdf')
```

At this point the code is executes but the folder `Data` was not created not am i able to locate `data.pdf`. I did get sucessful run though:

```
Loading pages (1/6)
Counting pages (2/6)                                               
Resolving links (4/6)                                                       
Loading headers and footers (5/6)                                           
Printing pages (6/6)
Done
```

Any ideas on how i can get this working correctly? The code does not produce the folder or the file?

Comment: You use the text `"relative_path"` in your call to `pdfkit.from_url` but you need to use the variable `relative_path`. Construct your final destination with `os.path.join(relative_path, 'data.pdf')`.

Comment: You need to construct the relative path to your current working directory, At the moment you use the relative path between `f"/home/{username}/Data"` and `start = f"/home/{username}"` and that will always be `"Data"`. So you try to use the filepath `Data/data.pdf` relative to your current working directory. Why use a relative path anyway?

Comment: To elaborate: your relative path should look like this: `relative_path = os.path.relpath(path, os.getcwd())` The variable `start` is superfluous.

Comment: @Matthias I did `relative_path = os.path.relpath(path, os.getcwd())
destination = os.path.join(relative_path, 'data.pdf')` When i `print(relative_path)` it is even showing me the correct path now but i am still getting the error: Error: Unable to write to destination                              
Exit with code 1, due to unknown error.

Comment: @Matthias I have updated the code in the question. If i do not include destination in `destination\data.pdf' the pdf is generated but for some reason it is not accepting the symbolic`destination` path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check by putting 
relative_path line before os.makedirs

As below

```
import pdfkit
import datetime as date
import calendar
import os.path
import getpass

username = getpass.getuser()

#path = os.path.join("home","{username}","Data")
# in case of window you will need to add drive "c:" or "d:" before os.path.sep
path = os.path.join(,"home",username,"Data")
relative_path = os.path.relpath(path, os.getcwd())
os.makedirs(relative_path, exist_ok=True)
#start = os.getcwd()
destination = os.path.join(relative_path, 'data.pdf')

pdfkit.from_url('www.google.com', f'{relative_path}/data.pdf')
```

Comment: I executed you code exactly but was not able to find data.pdf when i ran a search for it on C:/ Very curious where is this file being created?

Comment: `relative_path

Out[66]: '..\\..\\..\\home\\{user name}\\Data'`
This is my relative path

Comment: kindly check now

Comment: It worked but it created folder `home`,`{username}`, `Data` and then `data.pdf` in the current directory.

Comment: I have edited the code and also added the changes that will needed in windows system

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could change your last line to:

```
pdfkit.from_url('www.google.com', f'{relative_path}/data.pdf')
```

in order to get it to save to the home directory.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the issue is that the directory doesn't exist. You could use os.makedirs to create the directory, using the exist_ok=True flag in case the directory already exists. Like so:

```
import datetime as date
import os
import pdfkit

import getpass #Gets me current username

username = getpass.getuser()

path = f"/home/{username}/Data"
os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)
pdfkit.from_url('www.google.com', f'{path}/data.pdf')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, for a minute there i thought it worked. `
`os.makedirs(relative_path, exist_ok=True)
relative_path = os.path.relpath(path, os.getcwd())
destination = os.path.join(relative_path, 'data.pdf')
pdfkit.from_url('www.google.com', f'{relative_path}/data.pdf')` The code is working but for some reason the folder `Data` was not created, i am not sure where it created that file `data.pdf`. But it successfully ran, which is odd

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ). Run this little script on your machine:

```
import os

for key, value in os.environ.items():
    print(key, '-->', value)
```

and see for yourself what you need exactly. It's portable as well.

Let's say you want to get the path of the user's home directory. You could get it from `os.environ['HOME']` and then create the path to the target directory using `os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], 'target_directory_name')`.

You won't be able to create files in a directory if you don't have the required permissions, though.

Comment: I am very new to python, could you please elaborate on how i could use APPDATA?

Comment: I have added an example. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

User folders in windows are stored in "/Users/{username}/*". I don't know if you are trying to make this compatible for multiple OSs but if you just want to make this run on windows try:

```
path = f"/Users/{username}/Data"
start = f"/Users/{username}"
```

Hope it works.:)

Edit:
To get the home directory of a user regardless of OS you could use

```
from pathlib import Path
home = str(Path.home())
```

sorry for the late edit.

Comment: I want to make it compatible for multiple OSs